# how to fit RelativeLayout after a Scale Animation

Tags: android, scale, android-relativelayout

After apply this animation to my (chield)RelativeLayout, my backgroud image has the good size but my Layout seem to continue to take to much place on my Page (parent)RelativeLayout. Some idea?

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.2"
    android:toYScale="0.2"
    android:duration="700"
    >
</scale>
</set>

<RelativeLayout ...>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chieldLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bigImage"
    >
    <Button
        style="@style/boutonBrun"
        android:id="@+id/btPanier"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/full22lightgreen"

        />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have add like you propose me a listener to fit my layout with this command :

```
params.width = (int)  getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.size_width);
```

how can I know the "size_width" that I have to put? Like I ask to scale from 1.0 to 0.2 and finaly put android:layout_width="300dp", I have imagine that "size_width" have to take 60dp (300 * 0.2) but it's very to small compare to size after the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use animation listener like this

```
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // set height for your relative layout here
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your problem correctly but you can add an animation listener to your animation:

```
yourAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                     }
                  });
```

And in onAnimationEnd try to invalidate your view.

```
yourView.invalidate();
```

Comment: The problem is  when I apply the scale animation to my layout, he just change the background (for my it's a image) correctly but the Layout Itself seem to don't change size correctly (I know that because other element attach to him with android:layout_alignBottom="id..." don't move). So when I try to fit with the listener onAnimationEnd(), the layout seem to take the good size but in this case his background (image) is too small after. To resume : my scale animation don't change the size of layout imself but only his background . Thank you for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I just stop to use the param android:fillAfter="true", he seem to don't change the size of the layout... I just change size of my layout with onAnimationEnd.

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams();

  params.width = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.little_house_width);
  params.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.little_house_height);
  setLayoutParams(params);
```